# how to iterate over an arraylist using a loop, then using the get arraylist function to retrieve the information

Tags: java, android

I am trying to iterate over the array list to retrieve the sprites that I have stored in my array list, so I can display them on screen in my do draw method. The code below shows how I have tried to iterate over my array list.

```
 for (Sprite sprite: ArrayList) {

        ArrayList.get(numSprite);

    }
```

Comment: So, what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you must have some variable that holds a reference to your ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<Sprite> listVariable = ...
```

Your loop will be :

```
for (Sprite sprite : listVariable) {

}
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i < listVariable.size(); i++) {
    Sprite sprite = listVariable.get(i);
}
```

If you use the enhanced for loop (the first option), you don't need to call `get(index)`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way:

```
 Iterator<Sprite> iterator = arayList.iterator();
 while(iterator.hasNext()){
    Sprite item = iterator.next();
 }
```

To check that there are more items in the list, you have to call iterator.hasNext(), to retrieve the next item, you have to call iterator.next().

or

```
for(Sprite sprite: arrayList){
 //Do something with sprite object
}
```

in the for each,u can directly get the object of sprite from arrayList,no need to call arrayList.get() in your code.